# Catvba gui references wrong dll version

Tags: catia

I have a computer that has multiple releases of catia v5 installed (different customers require the work done in different releases), we recently installed   r26 and now the r19 catvba editor uses the r26 dlls, (which are not totally compatible and so vba code fails).  Any ideas on how to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a command window, go to the folder containing the cnext.exe (default of C:\Program Files\Dassault Systemes\B19\win_b64\code\bin for R19) for the specific version and run CNEXT.exe -regserver.

Comment: Thanks for the response (i cannot test it yet as i am off sick).

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem.